# Leveraging SQL Server to store a counter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to generate a unique caseid each time someone clicks on a button in a .Net windows application. My back-end is SQL Server 2008 R2.

Now this case id needs to be unique for each click by the users and it should start from 100 and keep incrementing.

Is it a bad practise to create a single column / single row table like let's say:

Table Counter: count int

That's all it will have. For each click in the button I will just keep incrementing it. Or is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 4):

You could create an int [IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) column in your table where the initial value is 100, and have it increment by one for each new row in the table. This is probably the most efficient (from a SQL Server perspective) way, and most concurrent friendly way, of doing it.